# Parenthesis error when I add one more UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a subquery of another query in which I have to show a lot of data, and I wanted to add a third **UNION** in the query. It should be noted that before adding the third **UNION** the query worked without problems, but when adding the third **UNION** it shows me an error of

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"
```

The line it indicates is a parenthesis just before the third **UNION**, but if I add it, everything falls apart and gives an error that the query is not closing properly and thus a loop. Searching I have seen that it may be because of the **order by** that does not support them when there are multiple **unions**, but with two it already works, I do not understand it.

This is the entire subquery:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ROWNUM RNUM,
        SUBQUERY.*
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID SESSION_SERVICE_CATALOG_ID,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_ES,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_EN,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_ES,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_EN,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_ID,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_ES,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_EN,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_ID,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ALARM_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ALARM_DAYS,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ADVANCE_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ADVANCE_DAYS,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.COST_BY_STUDENT CES_CATALOG_COST_BY_STUDENT,
            MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.DESCRIPTION,
            SERVICES_TABLE.COST SESSION_SERVICE_COST,
            SERVICES_TABLE.NUM_ITEMS SESSION_SERVICE_NUM_ITEMS,
            SERVICES_TABLE.COMMENTS SESSION_SERVICE_COMMENTS,
            SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS,
            MT_CES_STATUS.TEXT_NAME_EN PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS_LITERAL,
            (
            SELECT
                LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN ASC
            )
        FROM
            FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_PROVIDERS P
        INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER MTP
        ON
            (MTP.ID = P.PROVIDER_ID)
        WHERE
            P.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID
        ) PROVIDER_LITERAL,
        (
        SELECT
            LISTAGG(PRO.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            PRO.NAME ASC
        )
    FROM
        FRM.SESIONCURSO SES
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE COU
    ON
        (
            SES.CURSO = COU.ID AND COU.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD PE
    ON
        (
            COU.PERIOD_ID = PE.ID AND PE.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM PRO
    ON
        (
            PE.PROGRAM_ID = PRO.ID AND PRO.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    WHERE
        PRO.ID != AS_PROGRAM.ID AND SES.HORAINICIO = SE.HORAINICIO AND(
            NVL(
                SE.AULA,
                (
                    NVL(
                        AS_COURSE.CLASSROOM_ID,
                        AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID
                    )
                )
            )
        ) =(
            NVL(
                SES.AULA,
                (
                    NVL(
                        COU.CLASSROOM_ID,
                        PRO.CLASSROOM_ID
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) PROGRAMS_NAME,
    AS_PROGRAM.PARTICIPANTS PROGRAM_PARTICIPANTS,
    SE.HORAINICIO SESSION_DATE,
    SE.ID SESSION_ID,
    '0' IS_SPECIAL_SESSION,
    SE.NOMBRE SESSION_TITLE,
    SERVICES_TABLE.ID SERVICE_ID,
    SERVICES_TABLE.PARTICIPANTS,
    SERVICES_TABLE.CLASSROOM_ID SERVICE_CLASSROOM_ID,
    SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_START,
    SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_END,
    (
    SELECT
        AUL.TEXT_CODE
    FROM
        FRM.MT_CLASSROOM AUL
    WHERE
        AUL.ID = NVL(
            SE.AULA,
            (
                NVL(
                    AS_COURSE.CLASSROOM_ID,
                    AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID
                )
            )
        )
) CALCULATED_CLASSROOM,
(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_CODE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        MTP.TEXT_CODE ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.CES_SESSION_SERVICES_CLASSROOMS P
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CLASSROOM MTP
ON
    (MTP.ID = P.CLASSROOM_ID)
WHERE
    P.SERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) SERVICE_CLASSROOMS,
SE.HORAINICIO +(1 / 1440 * SE.MINUTOS) SESSION_END_DATE,
AS_PROGRAM.STATUS_ID PROGRAM_STATUS_ID,
AS_PROGRAM.NAME PROGRAM_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_URI,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.ID
    FROM
        FRM.CES_MATERIALCOORD
    WHERE
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.SESSIONSERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) THEN '1' ELSE '0'
    END AS HASMATERIAL,
    SERVICES_TABLE.PENDING_SEND
FROM
    FRM.SESIONCURSO SE
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE ON
    (
        SE.CURSO = AS_COURSE.ID AND AS_COURSE.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD ON
    (
        AS_COURSE.PERIOD_ID = AS_PERIOD.ID AND AS_PERIOD.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM ON
    (
        AS_PERIOD.PROGRAM_ID = AS_PROGRAM.ID AND AS_PROGRAM.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.CES_SESSION_SERVICES SERVICES_TABLE
ON
    (
        SERVICES_TABLE.SESSION_ID = SE.ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_STATUS ON
    (
        MT_CES_STATUS.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS
    )
LEFT JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER ON
    (
        MT_CES_PROVIDER.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PROVIDER_ID
    )
WHERE
    AS_PROGRAM.ID = 'TEST'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID SESSION_SERVICE_CATALOG_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ALARM_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ALARM_DAYS,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ADVANCE_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ADVANCE_DAYS,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.COST_BY_STUDENT CES_CATALOG_COST_BY_STUDENT,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.DESCRIPTION,
    SERVICES_TABLE.COST SESSION_SERVICE_COST,
    SERVICES_TABLE.NUM_ITEMS SESSION_SERVICE_NUM_ITEMS,
    SERVICES_TABLE.COMMENTS SESSION_SERVICE_COMMENTS,
    SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS,
    MT_CES_STATUS.TEXT_NAME_EN PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS_LITERAL,
    (
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_PROVIDERS P
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER MTP
ON
    (MTP.ID = P.PROVIDER_ID)
WHERE
    P.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID
) PROVIDER_LITERAL,
(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(PRO.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        PRO.NAME ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.SESIONESPECIAL SES
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM PRO
ON
    (
        SES.IDPROGRAMA = PRO.ID AND PRO.REMOVED = '0'
    )
WHERE
    PRO.ID != AS_PROGRAM.ID AND SES.HORAINICIO = SE.HORAINICIO AND(
        NVL(
            SE.AULA,
            (AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID)
        )
    ) = NVL(SES.AULA, PRO.CLASSROOM_ID)
) PROGRAMS_NAME,
AS_PROGRAM.PARTICIPANTS PROGRAM_PARTICIPANTS,
SE.HORAINICIO SESSION_DATE,
SE.ID SESSION_ID,
'1' IS_SPECIAL_SESSION,
SE.NOMBRE SESSION_TITLE,
SERVICES_TABLE.ID SERVICE_ID,
SERVICES_TABLE.PARTICIPANTS,
SERVICES_TABLE.CLASSROOM_ID SERVICE_CLASSROOM_ID,
SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_START,
SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_END,
(
    SELECT
        AUL.TEXT_CODE
    FROM
        FRM.MT_CLASSROOM AUL
    WHERE
        AUL.ID = NVL(
            SE.AULA,
            AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID
        )
) CALCULATED_CLASSROOM,
(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_CODE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        MTP.TEXT_CODE ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.CES_SPECIAL_SESSION_SERVICES_CLASSROOMS P
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CLASSROOM MTP
ON
    (MTP.ID = P.CLASSROOM_ID)
WHERE
    P.SERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) SERVICE_CLASSROOMS,
SE.HORAINICIO +(1 / 1440 * SE.MINUTOS) SESSION_END_DATE,
AS_PROGRAM.STATUS_ID PROGRAM_STATUS_ID,
AS_PROGRAM.NAME PROGRAM_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_URI,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.ID
    FROM
        FRM.CES_MATERIALCOORD
    WHERE
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.SPECIALSESSIONSERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) THEN '1' ELSE '0'
END AS HASMATERIAL,
SERVICES_TABLE.PENDING_SEND
FROM
    FRM.SESIONESPECIAL SE
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM ON
    (
        SE.IDPROGRAMA = AS_PROGRAM.ID AND AS_PROGRAM.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.CES_SPECIAL_SESSION_SERVICES SERVICES_TABLE
ON
    (
        SERVICES_TABLE.SESSION_ID = SE.ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_STATUS ON
    (
        MT_CES_STATUS.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS
    )
LEFT JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER ON
    (
        MT_CES_PROVIDER.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PROVIDER_ID
    )
WHERE
    AS_PROGRAM.ID = 'TEST'
ORDER BY
    SERVICE_START
DESC
    ,
    SESSION_DATE
DESC
    ,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_EN
DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT
    SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID SESSION_SERVICE_CATALOG_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_ES MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_ES,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.TEXT_NAME_EN MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_TEXT_NAME_EN,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1_ID,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ALARM_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ALARM_DAYS,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ADVANCE_DAYS CES_CATALOG_ADVANCE_DAYS,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.COST_BY_STUDENT CES_CATALOG_COST_BY_STUDENT,
    MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.DESCRIPTION,
    SERVICES_TABLE.COST SESSION_SERVICE_COST,
    SERVICES_TABLE.NUM_ITEMS SESSION_SERVICE_NUM_ITEMS,
    SERVICES_TABLE.COMMENTS SESSION_SERVICE_COMMENTS,
    SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS,
    MT_CES_STATUS.TEXT_NAME_EN PROGRAM_SERVICE_STATUS_LITERAL,
    (
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        MTP.TEXT_NAME_EN ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_PROVIDERS P
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER MTP
ON
    (MTP.ID = P.PROVIDER_ID)
WHERE
    P.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3_ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID
) PROVIDER_LITERAL,
(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(PRO.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        PRO.NAME ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.SESIONCURSO SES
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE COU
ON
    (
        SES.CURSO = COU.ID AND COU.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD PE
ON
    (
        COU.PERIOD_ID = PE.ID AND PE.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM PRO
ON
    (
        PE.PROGRAM_ID = PRO.ID AND PRO.REMOVED = '0'
    )
WHERE
    PRO.ID != AS_PROGRAM.ID AND SES.HORAINICIO = SE.HORAINICIO AND(
        NVL(
            SE.AULA,
            (
                NVL(
                    AS_COURSE.CLASSROOM_ID,
                    AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID
                )
            )
        )
    ) =(
        NVL(
            SES.AULA,
            (
                NVL(
                    COU.CLASSROOM_ID,
                    PRO.CLASSROOM_ID
                )
            )
        )
    )
) PROGRAMS_NAME,
AS_PROGRAM.PARTICIPANTS PROGRAM_PARTICIPANTS,
SE.HORAINICIO SESSION_DATE,
SE.ID SESSION_ID,
'0' IS_SPECIAL_SESSION,
SE.NOMBRE SESSION_TITLE,
SERVICES_TABLE.ID SERVICE_ID,
SERVICES_TABLE.PARTICIPANTS,
SERVICES_TABLE.CLASSROOM_ID SERVICE_CLASSROOM_ID,
SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_START,
SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_END,
(
    SELECT
        AUL.TEXT_CODE
    FROM
        FRM.MT_CLASSROOM AUL
    WHERE
        AUL.ID = NVL(
            SE.AULA,
            (
                NVL(
                    AS_COURSE.CLASSROOM_ID,
                    AS_PROGRAM.CLASSROOM_ID
                )
            )
        )
) CALCULATED_CLASSROOM,
(
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(MTP.TEXT_CODE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        MTP.TEXT_CODE ASC
    )
FROM
    FRM.CES_SESSION_SERVICES_CLASSROOMS P
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CLASSROOM MTP
ON
    (MTP.ID = P.CLASSROOM_ID)
WHERE
    P.SERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) SERVICE_CLASSROOMS,
SE.HORAINICIO +(1 / 1440 * SE.MINUTOS) SESSION_END_DATE,
AS_PROGRAM.STATUS_ID PROGRAM_STATUS_ID,
AS_PROGRAM.NAME PROGRAM_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_NAME,
MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.EXT_LINK_URI,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.ID
    FROM
        FRM.CES_MATERIALCOORD
    WHERE
        CES_MATERIALCOORD.SESSIONSERVICE_ID = SERVICES_TABLE.ID
) THEN '1' ELSE '0'
END AS HASMATERIAL,
SERVICES_TABLE.PENDING_SEND
FROM
    FRM.SESIONCURSO SE
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE ON
    (
        SE.CURSO = AS_COURSE.ID AND AS_COURSE.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD ON
    (
        AS_COURSE.PERIOD_ID = AS_PERIOD.ID AND AS_PERIOD.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM ON
    (
        AS_PERIOD.PROGRAM_ID = AS_PROGRAM.ID AND AS_PROGRAM.REMOVED = '0'
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.CES_SESSION_SERVICES SERVICES_TABLE
ON
    (
        SERVICES_TABLE.SESSION_ID = SE.ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.SERVICE_ID
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1 ON
    (
        MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_1.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_2.PARENT_SERVICE
    )
INNER JOIN FRM.MT_CES_STATUS ON
    (
        MT_CES_STATUS.ID = SERVICES_TABLE.STATUS
    )
LEFT JOIN FRM.MT_CES_PROVIDER ON
    (
        MT_CES_PROVIDER.ID = MT_CES_SERVICE_LEVEL_3.PROVIDER_ID
    )
WHERE
    SE.ID IN(
    SELECT
        SES.ID
    FROM
        FRM.SESIONCURSO SES
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE COU
    ON
        (
            SES.CURSO = COU.ID AND COU.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD PE
    ON
        (
            COU.PERIOD_ID = PE.ID AND PE.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM PRO
    ON
        (
            PE.PROGRAM_ID = PRO.ID AND PRO.REMOVED = '0'
        )
    WHERE
        SES.HORAINICIO =(
        SELECT
            SES2.HORAINICIO
        FROM
            FRM.SESIONCURSO SES2
        WHERE
            SES2.ID = 'TEST'
    ) AND(
        NVL(
            SES.AULA,
            (
                NVL(
                    COU.CLASSROOM_ID,
                    PRO.CLASSROOM_ID
                )
            )
        ) =(
        SELECT
            NVL(
                SES2.AULA,
                (
                    NVL(
                        COU2.CLASSROOM_ID,
                        PRO2.CLASSROOM_ID
                    )
                )
            )
        FROM
            FRM.SESIONCURSO SES2
        INNER JOIN FRM.AS_COURSE COU2
        ON
            (
                SES2.CURSO = COU2.ID AND COU2.REMOVED = '0'
            )
        INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PERIOD PE2
        ON
            (
                COU2.PERIOD_ID = PE2.ID AND PE2.REMOVED = '0'
            )
        INNER JOIN FRM.AS_PROGRAM PRO2
        ON
            (
                PE2.PROGRAM_ID = PRO2.ID AND PRO2.REMOVED = '0'
            )
        WHERE
            SES2.ID = 'TEST'
    )
    )
)
) SUBQUERY
WHERE
    ROWNUM <= 1000
)
WHERE
    RNUM > 0;
```

Comment: You're confusing the `order by` clauses that as are part of the `listagg()` syntax - which is fine in a subquery - with the `order by` of a result set - which is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about the `ORDER BY` clause; you can't sort each `select` statement separately, but the whole result set.

**No**:

```
select * from 
(select first_query
   from some_table
   order by whatever       --> this can't be here
 UNION ALL
 select second_query
   from another_table
)
where some_condition;
```

**Yes #1**:

```
select * from 
(select first_query
   from some_table
 UNION ALL
 select second_query
   from another_table
)
where some_condition
order by whatever;         --> should be here
```

**Yes #2**:

```
select * from 
(select first_query
   from some_table
 UNION ALL
 select second_query
   from another_table
 order by whatever         --> should be here
)
where some_condition
```

Comment: But the first two queries have several order by and return data, adding the third query throws an error.

Comment: These ORDER BYs are part of LISTAGG function (which is irrelevant here).

Comment: It is true that adding the third query if I remove the order by from the second query the entire query works, but if I leave the first two queries with the order by from the second query it works the same or is it that using UNION you can only order one?

Comment: That's because ORDER BY is then at the end of SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2. Once you added SELECT 3, then ORDER BY must be at the end. Could be within the parenthesis or outside (as in pseudocode I posted), but it can't be "in the middle" of the query.

Comment: Ok, it's much clearer to me now. Thanks so much for the explanation.